# SetState in Class Component is not running (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass an ID of a specific gallery-image to it's details page which is a child-component of gallery.

To achieve this I call an onClick-Function, `handleClick`, when the image is selected. (So that the key is passed as new prop to the child-component)

The onClick-function is but the setState within will not be executed.

The state doesn't change and the key `(this.state.key)` is not passed as a new value (nextprop) to the child-component.

Here is my code:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { GridList, GridListTile } from "@material-ui/core";
import ImageList from '@material-ui/core/ImageList'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ImageListItem } from '@material-ui/core'
import { ImageListItemBar } from '@material-ui/core';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from '../styles/ImageGallery.module.scss';
import Delete from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import FavoriteBorder from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteBorder';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link} from "react-router-dom";
import ItemDetail from "../pages/Items";

export default class IGallery extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);    
/*       this.countryList = {
        key: 'test',
        name:'test'
      } */
      //this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

      this.state = {
         countryList: [],
         wallet:'',
         key:''    }
     
      this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
      this.socket.on('new_data', (value) => this.handleMessage(value));
   
      this.socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      this.socket.disconnect();
    });
     
    }

    handleMessage(value) {

   
       let imageDataSet=(JSON.parse(value).new_val);
       console.log("New Data "+value['new_val']);
       //let imageDataSet = value2.new_val;
       console.log("Test "+imageDataSet);
       //console.log("Test "+imageDataSet.id);
      this.setState({
          countryList: [ ...this.state.countryList, {key:imageDataSet.id, image:imageDataSet.image}, ],
      }) 
    
    }


    handleClick = (_key) => {
        console.log("Key of Gallery Image "+_key);
        console.log('before setState', this.state.key)
        this.setState({key:_key}, console.log('after setState', this.state.key));
  
      
    }


    render()
    {

    return (

        <div className={styles.gallery}><h1>Gallery</h1>
         
    
    <ImageList cols={6} rowHeight={320}>
        {this.state.countryList.map((data, idx) => (
         <ImageListItem  key={idx} className={styles.imageItem}>
           <Link to="/item" onClick={() => this.handleClick(data.key)}>
            <img src={data.image}  width={320} /><ItemDetail key={this.state.key}></ItemDetail> 
           </Link>
          </ImageListItem >
        ))}
      </ImageList >
     
        </div>
      );
    }
    
  }
```

I expect that the console-log displays the  new state.

```
   this.setState({key:_key}, console.log('after setState', this.state.key));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` works asynchronously, You cannot get its value soon after it is set, it would take some time.

To know if the `state` is set use the `useEffect` with the `state` dependency.

```
useEffect(()
  {console.log(this.state.key)} 
   // If you want to navigate to Details page once key is set 
   .....   Navigate to Details Screen with prop of key here
,[this.state.key]);  Add your dependency state here
```

Comment: But useEffect can't be used in Class Components. I used componentDidUpdate instead but the result is the same: no update on state "key".

Comment: Okay you're right. It lasts some seconds before update but how can I pass the id to the details-page. Right after the click the state is not updated and so the props stay the same

Answer (score 1):

From [setState() documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

So you must pass a **callback** (instead of calling directly `console.log`)

```js
this.setState({key:_key}, () => console.log('after setState', this.state.key));
```